# Working with Zend Session Namespaces across multiple requests

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, namespaces

Maybe I'm just not seeing it, but is there any other way to access a previously created session namespace, other than calling `$_SESSION` directly? Besides the fact that I **really** don't want to do this, the Zend documentation also [advises against this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.basic_usage.html):

> while $_SESSION is still available in
>   PHP's global namespace, developers
>   should refrain from directly accessing
>   it, so that Zend_Session and
>   Zend_Session_Namespace can most
>   effectively and securely provide its
>   suite of session related
>   functionality.

The Zend_Session_Namespace class doesn't have a static method for getting a namespace, and although the now deprecated [`namespaceGet`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/_Session.html#Zend_Session%3a%3anamespaceGet%28%29) method in Zend_Session instructs me to use [`Zend_Session_Namespace#getIterator`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/_Session_Namespace.html#Zend_Session_Namespace%3a%3agetIterator%28%29), that method is not static.

So that means I need to initialize a new namespace, using the `new` keyword. The problem is, this doesn't include previously set variables:

```
$ns = new Zend_Session_Namespace('foo');
$ns->foo = 'bar';
```

On a subsequent request, this:

```
print_R(new Zend_Session_Namespace('Foo'));
```

...prints this:

```
Zend_Session_Namespace Object
(
    [_namespace:protected] => Foo
)
```

which seems obvious.

So how am I supposed to fetch the previously created namespace, without using `$_SESSION['Foo']`?

Comment: Tim already answered this: using the `new` operator. Since you seem to search for a `static` method: afaik there isn't, but of course you are free to write your own static factory singleton, if you want to avoid to have dozens of `new Zend_Session_Namespace()` declarations spreaded all over your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The case of your two code examples doesn't match (foo vs. Foo), I'm not sure if that was just a typo or not. Zend_Session_Namespace is just a wrapper for $_SESSION, so all you need to do is create a namespace object with the same key and then all your data should be available.

```
$ns = new Zend_Session_Namespace('foo');
$ns->foo = 'bar';
```

and then on another page:

```
$ns = new Zend_Session_Namespace('foo');
echo $ns->foo; // should output bar
```

if this doesn't work then there is a problem with your session configuration.

Comment: The case fault is a typo indeed. I was mistaken though, accessing the properties actually works, although the `print_r` did not show them. Must be at it too long I suppose... sorry to waste your time!

Comment: The print_r may be misleading as the data is still stored in $_SESSION (so won't be shown when you print_r), the namespace class just accesses it from there.

Comment: what is to be imported for the Zend_Session_Namespace();