# Zend framework session management for multiple module application

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-modules

I'm having a ZF application with two different modules 1.default and 2.admin and I'm setting some session values in default module however I'm not able to get the session value which i set in default module in admin module.Is there anyway to make session GLOBAL, I mean accessible to all modules in the application?

Comment: post the code on how you are setting the session values

Comment: //In default module
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Zend_Auth');
$session->a = 1;
//In admin
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Zend_Auth');
echo $session->a; //Im not getting this

Comment: instead of 'Zend_Auth' try something dummy like 'foo'

Comment: Still cant access the session :(

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623599/working-with-zend-session-namespaces-across-multiple-requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it on my own

We cant get Zend_session_Namespace of one module in another ,rather we can get $_SESSION in both modules

So in the bootstrap

```
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('auth');
$session = $_SESSION;
```